# The "timelines" tag - another one with two meanings

Tags: discussion, tags

The wiki for [timelines](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timelines) reads:

> This tag should be used for timelines for an author, such as the amount of time between publishing different parts of a blog series, **or** for questions about timelines in written works, such as problems with aligning different timelines because of different PoV's or time-travelling.

All 11 questions use the second meaning. Maybe get rid of the first?

Is there sufficient difference between [timelines](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timelines) and [time-depiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-depiction) to justify having both, instead of merging [timelines] into [time-depiction]?

### Update:

I've edited [timelines](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timelines) wiki to include only the second meaning. We can discuss merging or not merging it into [time-depiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-depiction).

For the first meaning, we can create [schedule](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schedule), even copy-paste the stuff from [timelines]'s wiki editing history into the new tag's wiki (rather than writing the wiki from scratch). 26 questions currently have the word 'schedule' in the body of the question (I haven't gone over the search results to see their actual relevance). We also have [time-management](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-management), we should discuss how those two do/do not overlap. None of the "schedule" questions had a [timelines] tag, proving that its intuitive use is for story timelines.

Comment: The first one sounds more like scheduling to me.

Comment: To me, when I see the word timeline on [WSE](https://writing.stackexchange.com), my mind goes to the story timeline. I recommend providing a new tag for the former meaning you mentioned. We could consider _schedule_, _deadline_, _progress_, or even _timetable_ `£`.

Comment: Certainly the second half of that def should be under [tag:time-depiction].  The first half is reasonable but might be confusing even with better wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is also ignoring a third potential meaning:

1. Time Scheduling
2. Time Depiction/Event Progression
3. Parallel Timelines in the sense of stories involving split timelines like Steins;Gate, Travelers, and 11/22/63. (As opposed to stories about Other Worlds, Parallel Dimensions, etc.)

I think we should try to separate the three potential interpretations as much as possible simply so that there is no misunderstanding of the tag's intended meaning. Right now, it's not used much at all, but any potential confusion should probably be avoided as early as possible.